# How do I bind my left click to a button?

Tags: autohotkey

Im using AHK (AutoHotKey) to try and bind my X button to be left click (When X is pressed it would act like a left click) for game usage.
I am confused on how to do it.
If you know, please help.

Answer (score 1):

To remap a key, you use the syntax `OriginKey::DestinationKey`. For you to use your <kbd>x</kbd> as a <kbd>Left Click</kbd> you would simply do `x::LButton`. You can make it a bit more fancy, but that syntax itself will remap the key that you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment - not enough rep but this should help:

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/54265-make-a-key-on-the-keyboard-like-left-click/